# How/Do I change a custom UIView's frame manually?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, frame

I have a custom UIView `fooView`, where I've overridden the `drawRect` method, with an `initWithFrame` method.

I also have a custom UIView `barView` which holds and contains `fooView`.

`barView` is supposed to get it's height from `fooView` since `fooView` is drawing custom stuff.

My problem is everytime I check for `fooView`'s `frame`, or `bounds` property, it remains the same. Even though I can clearly see it outgrowing the initial height dictated by the `initWithFrame`.

Which leads me to believe that maybe since I've overridden the `drawRect` method, now it's my responsibility to update `fooView`'s frame.

Should I do this?
How would I do this?
What is the best practice?

---

EDIT: Added Code

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)   [self setupWithMessage:nil];
    return self;
}
```

`setupWithMessage` just calculates the dimensions (mainly height) required for text to fit in a constrained width.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [super drawRect:rect];
//  a whole bunch of drawing logic, but basically draws a message bubble
//  based on the size of the text (The text dynamically changes), and then
//  draws the text so if there is a lot of text, the calculated height of
//  what it takes to draw the text  can easily be larger than the size
//  originally passed in during initialization
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some code?

For example your's drawRect: and initWithFrame: implementation

Comment: @YuriRomanchenko I'll put it up right now

Comment: Even though you are drawing outside of `fooView`'s frame, its width and height does not get updated, yet the content outside of `fooView`'s frame is still visible, assuming you are not setting `clipsToBounds` on `barView`.

Comment: @bobnoble my question exactly is how do you update the width and height after I've drawn my stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `drawInRect:(CGRect)rect` gives you a rect that is not greater than your's view frame.

So if you draw in rect that is higher that given `rect` - your drawings will be clipped.

So steps that you should do:

- Calculate all dimensions and **set** your's `fooView` frame.
- After that you should call `[fooView setNeedsDisplay]`.
- It will invoke your `drawInRect:` method with a new frame, so you can focus there on drawing.

If your `fooView` main task is to draw **given** text from `barView` I suggest you to create `@property (nonatomic) NSString *textToDraw;` in `fooView` class and override setter in which you will follow steps above.

EDIT:
As I see you created a `setupWithText:` method for this purposes. So you need to calculate all dimensions, set frame `self.frame = (CGRect){previousX, previousY, newWidth, newHeight}` and call `[self setNeedsDisplay];`

Comment: so I do actually have to change my own frame. Brilliant! thank's for your help